# user.save is not a function Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am trying to invalidating the token, if token is present in the mongodb database, but I am geting an error user.save() is not a function. how to resolve this?

```
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const code = req.body.code;
    console.log(code + "code");
 
    let profile = await verifyIdToken(code);
    console.log(profile + "signinuser");
    const newUser = {
      uid: profile.uid,
      name: profile.name,
      email: profile.email,
      paymentUpdated: false,
      isLoggedIn: true,
 
      userBrowser: req.headers["user-agent"]
      
};

    let user = await db.aggregate('USER', query);
    console.log(user + "data1");
    user = user[0];
    user = await db.findOne('USER', {email:newUser.email});
    if(user.accessToken!='') {
      user.accessToken='';
      user.refreshToken='';
      console.log("Hello");   
      await user.save();                                                                               
    }
    if (!user ) {
      user = await db.create('USER', newUser);
    }
   
    const token = generateToken(user);
    res.status(200).json({ user, token });
   
     user = await db.findOneAndUpdate('USER', { email: newUser.email }, {$set:{accessToken:token}})


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)                                                                                             
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

why user.save is not a function, dont know what wrong I am doing?

Comment: What is `db.findOne('USER')`? Why aren't you using a Mongoose model there?

Comment: USER is the name given to the userSchema

Comment: This is the nomenclature used in the project. What should be beneficial to use? @robertklep

Comment: Is it something you implemented yourself? It looks like the problem is that it doesn't return a Mongoose document, which means you can't call Mongoose methods on it.

Comment: Yes, i made the changes and then its geting saved.
@robertklep: can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289139/login-from-single-device-at-a-time-logout-others-mern-jwt-google-login

Answer (score 0):

What it returns if you do a console.log(user) before await user.save()? maybe is not returning a valid value to save.

Comment: its returning the values when done console.log() before user.save

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).